# I need help in Linear regression with python?

Tags: python, data-science

so I used red wine quality Dataset from kaggle to implement everything that I've learned about linear regression. These are the results. Since the value of skew was 0.3 I didn't transform my target by taking log. As you can see I've dropped a lot features from the Dataframe because they had 0.05 above result of P values. Is it safe to drop the ones that exceeds the limit or is there any method to optimize them? Am I doing good so far or is there any mistake? Thank you.[image: Results]

Comment: You should include some code to show your attemts so far.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to exclude the variables with non-significant coefficients the answer is yes. It is fine to remove them. As you can see after remove those the results do not change much, apparently they only introduce noice.

Comment: Yeah, variables. Thanks. The values doesn't change much so that's why I excluded them because they gave lesser mean square error.